# Android Google Plus API - PeopleApi.loadConnected returns 0 persons

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to get all the Google+ friends that logged into the app.

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
```

Returns an Array of all the visible people in Google+ but

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadConnected(mGoogleApiClient)
```

Returns an empty buffer. I'm sure that there should be at least one connected friend since we've both logged into the app.

Also we've both authorized the app to see everyone in the circles and access people data.

Does anyone know how to correctly get the connected people info?

Comment: Are you sure that you have Required Scope SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN?

Comment: Yes. As I've said, I am getting all visible people so that shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: Can you include your code for setting mGoogleApiClient and the code for using the PendingResult object that you receive from each of the two methods?